# Transfering all rows to devexpress xtragrid on selecting single row

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, devexpress, xtragrid

currently i have my grid that loads more than 2 or 3 pending data.
 
If i need to accept all the pending data i need to right click on the single row and click accept all to transfer all the data.
Can any one help me how to send all the row in the grid to perform transfer on selecting single row.

**Here is my Image:**

[image]

**My Code:**

```
private void acceptPendingTransfer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Account dvo = new Account();

            try
            {  
                switch (sender.ToString())
                {
                    case "Accept" :
                        dvo.accountTransferId = getSelectedTransferId();
                        accountClient.acceptTransfer(dvo);
                        goto case "Refresh";
                    case "AcceptAll" :
                        dvo.accountTransferId = getSelectedTransferId();
                        accountClient.acceptAllTransfer(dvo);
                        goto case "Refresh";
                    case "Reject":
                        dvo.accountTransferId = getSelectedTransferId();
                        accountClient.rejectTransfer(dvo);
                        goto case "Refresh";
                    case "RejectAll":
                        dvo.accountTransferId = getSelectedTransferId();
                        accountClient.rejectAllTransfer(dvo);
                        goto case "Refresh";
                    case "Refresh":
                        AppUtil.ShowInformationMessage("Transferred successfully");
                        if (showAllPendingTransfers.Checked)
                            populateTransfers(true);
                        else
                            populateTransfers(false);
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AppUtil.ShowErrorMessage(ex.Message);
            }
        }

**getSelectedTransferId**<br>

private long getSelectedTransferId()
        {
            return (long)this.gridPendingTransfersView.GetFocusedRowCellValue("Id");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get IDs of all selected rows using:

```
private IEnumerable<long> getSelectedTransferIds()
{
    return gridPendingTransfersView.GetSelectedRows()
        .Select(x => gridPendingTransfersView.GetRowCellValue(x, "Id"))
        .Cast<long>();
}
```

Your original code would become something like:

```
case "AcceptAll" :
    foreach (var id in getSelectedTransferIds())
    {
        Account dvo = new Account { accountTransferId = id };
        accountClient.acceptAllTransfer(dvo);
    }
    goto case "Refresh";
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you could use the `DataSource` list used to populate your grid.
It contains the whole set of rows.

So, if it is not the case, declare the object used as the `DataSource` as a global variable and use it along.